# How to send outer variable to a vue component

Tags: vue.js

I have a `Vue Component` called `send-sms-btn` which is next to an input tag like below :

```html
<input v-model="number" placeholder="enter your phone number..." >
<send-sms-btn></send-sms-btn>
```

As you can see when user enters the phone number in the input it saves in to a data called `number`, but how can I pass this data to my `send-sms-btn` component?

Answer (score 1):

you can use props in this case

```
<send-sms-btn :enteredNumber="number"></send-sms-btn>
```

and inside your send-sms component you can receieve it in the props section like

```
props: ['enteredNumber']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as prop like :

```js
<input v-model="number" placeholder="enter your phone number..." >
<send-sms-btn :number="number" ></send-sms-btn>
```

and `send-sms-btn` component should define that prop :

```js
export default{
  name:'send-sms-btn',
  props:['number']
```